# 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable or not local

Tags: .net, email, sendmail, mail-server

Have set up a small website for a client however contact form submissions are not getting through to their email address.

The bounce back has this message attached:

```
550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable or not local
```

It sends without issue to my email address and others but can't get to any on their domain.

Client's IT guy is a bit clueless so I'm unsure how he's configured the mail server?

Comment: I should also point out that the website shares same domain as email address' however the web server and email server are hosted @ different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, was due to webserver having max entries which meant it was trying to send mail to itself rather than the external mail server.

Deleting DNS entries fixed the problem.

Comment: Do you mean MX entries?

Comment: How did you delete DNS entries?  And from where / on what box or server did you delete them?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably sending the emails to an incorrect email address, or possible the emails are being sent to the http server for the domain (or similar) but the SMTP server is hosted elsewhere.

Comment: you're correct the SMTP servers are hosted elsewhere, how do I specify to send mail to these rather than the HTTP servers?

Comment: @timothy: I'd assume that you just need to have the correct MX records set up in the correct locations but I don't do much DNS admin. I'd suggest asking that on serverfault.com.